# Countif: How many times element in one dataframe is in another dataframe

Tags: r, lapply, countif, mapply

I am trying to write code to count how many times I have 1 element of a dataframe in a three columns of another dataframe.  I know I need to use an apply loop but not sure how to write it.

Example:

df

```
   state
1     OR
2     TX
3     MI
4     MA
5     IA
6     CA
```

data

```
ST  ST2 ST3
OR      
        MI
        SC
        TN
TX      
        KY
        OH
        MN
MI      
        IA
        NC
        MA
        MI
MA      
        KY
        MI
IA      
        IA
    MO  
CA      
        TN
    PA  
        KY
IL
```

I want to know how many times a entry in "df" for example OR is in data, TX is in data, and so forth.  This code below does not work.  I unlisted data as a vector called 'statteUnlist" and it works if I just test for example == "OR" in below code but I need an apply loop to go through all entries of df.

```
length(which(stateUnlist == df$state))
```

Above code does not work, but below code does. How do I loop through all entries of df?

```
length(which(stateUnlist == "OR"))
```

desired result below (FYI these are the total data from the excel so total will differ)

```
   state n
1     OR 2
2     TX 2
3     MI 8
4     MA 4
5     IA 6
6     CA 2
7     IL 8
8     MO 2
9     PA 2
10    SC 2
11    TN 4
12    KY 6
13    OH 2
14    MN 2
15    NC 2
```

Comment: Please show desired result from posted examples.

Comment: version 3.3.2 libraries used are (XL Connect)

Comment: Is that an answer to my request?

Comment: yes, did i do it right?

Comment: Better. Thanks. But how is OR and TX at 2 count from posted example?

Comment: i didn't post the full data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get counts of `data` with

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data.frame(table(unlist(data))) %>%
           setNames(c("state","n"))
```

Then filter for those in `df`

```
data2 <- left_join(df, data1, by="state")
```

Comment: thanks Chi.  I realized I cannot use the split and sapply function now after doing some testing because my df with unique state names would have to be a factor of the total length of the data vector.  i tested and made it a multiple and get same answer.  your code will help in the future.  FYI i did get this warning: `Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`

Comment: oh shoot so yes there is another package you near to run `%>%`.  You need the `magrittr , dplyr` packages

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about libraries. I've updated my answer.

Comment: There is a good swirl tutorial that explains the %>% operator for dplyr if you install the specific swirl package from the Data Science Specialization below.  It's the first and second exercises for dplyr.  The %>% should be read as "then" and shortens having to re-enter your data frame.    https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-cleaning/supplement/kPOKW/practical-r-exercises-in-swirl-part-1

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get your answer is to specify your columns in the 'select' in code below.  I forgot to indicate that the first df in my example is just a new data frame of unique values I got in my second 'data' data frame.  Chi's answer is still correct for if you are give two data frames.

```
data %>%
select(ST:ST3) %>%
gather(key, value, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
count(value)
```

or you can reference the entire data frame using code below.  'State' is just an example of name of column after you gather and value is a default column 2 for the gathered value in all the columns.  You don't want to name your column 'value' because it will duplicate column names.

```
count((gather(data, State, na.rm = TRUE)), value)
```